# How can I change name of the uploaded file to firebase storage?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have created storage reference and described it to file which I want to change the name of it. But storage reference has no method related to my goal.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the image name like this:

```
storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
String ts = tsLong.toString();
StorageReference storageReference = storage.child("image").child(ts + ".jpg");
```

Comment: I tried it , but it didn't work . Image name is still same . thanks for answer .

Answer (score 1):

I did this to rename the files with the time and date.

```js
Log.d(TAG, "uploadFromUri:src:" + fileUri.toString());
String time = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString();
Log.d(TAG, "uploadFromUri: time " + time);

storageRef = storage.getReference().child("/dir/"+firebaseUser.getUid()+"/"+time+"/");

UploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(fileUri);
```

Answer (score -2):

Just use this code.. I found it useful for me. It's kotlin code.

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
val PDF : Int = 0
val DOCX : Int = 1
val PPT : Int = 2
lateinit var uri : Uri
lateinit var mStorage : StorageReference

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val pdfBtn = findViewById<View>(R.id.pdfBtn) as Button
    val docxBtn = findViewById<View>(R.id.docxBtn) as Button
    val pptBtn = findViewById<View>(R.id.pptBtn) as Button


    mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Uploads")

    pdfBtn.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        view: View? -> val intent = Intent()
        intent.setType ("*/*")
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select PDF"), PDF)
    })

    docxBtn.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        view: View? -> val intent = Intent()
        intent.setType ("*/*")
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select DOCX"), DOCX)
    })

    pptBtn.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        view: View? -> val intent = Intent()
        intent.setType ("*/*")
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select PPT"), PPT)
    })

}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    val uriTxt = findViewById<View>(R.id.uriTxt) as TextView
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == PDF) {
            uri = data!!.data
            uriTxt.text = uri.toString()
            upload ()
        }else if (requestCode == DOCX) {
            uri = data!!.data
            uriTxt.text = uri.toString()
            upload ()
        }
        else if (requestCode == PPT) {
            uri = data!!.data
            uriTxt.text = uri.toString()
            upload ()
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}

private fun upload() {
    var mReference = mStorage.child(uri.lastPathSegment)
    try {
        mReference.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener {
            taskSnapshot: UploadTask.TaskSnapshot? -> var url = taskSnapshot!!.downloadUrl
            val dwnTxt = findViewById<View>(R.id.dwnTxt) as TextView
            dwnTxt.text = url.toString()
            Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully Uploaded :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }catch (e: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

}
```

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written